# Match regex containing whole word using list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the code below that works

```
lista= ['abd','bda']
for element in lista:
    df[element] = df['concatenated_string'].str.contains(element, regex=True)

df
          concatenated_string
0         abdar___
1         abd___
2         asd_ab_ad______
```

How could I match on the whole word instead? So a value for "abdar" in the concatenated_string column should not be picked up. I tried:

```
for element in lista:
    df[element] = df['concatenated_string'].str.contains("\b(element)\b", regex=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `f-string`, [literal string interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":["I was", "I wasn't"]})
els = ["was"]

for element in els:
    df["element"] = df["a"].str.contains(f"\\b{element}\\b", regex=True)
    
df
          a  element
0     I was     True
1  I wasn't    False
```

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the question since this code gave a False, maybe because of the underscore?

Comment: Try `df['col'].str.replace("_"," ").str.contains(...)`

Comment: Perfect! Would you mind explaining why it didn't work when the column contains underscores?

Comment: "\b" regex matches on word boundaries. "_" doesn't qualify as such.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for element in lista:
    df[element] = df['concatenated_string'].str.contains(" " +element+ " ", regex=True)
```